# Python Socket takes forever only on first iteration of loop?

Tags: python, sockets

The title says it all. The loop takes forever for the first port and then the rest of them only take one second.

```
import socket
target = "192.168.0.104"


try:
    for port in range(52,85):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
        result=s.connect_ex((target,port))
        if result == 0:
            print("Port {} is open".format(port))
        else:
            print("Port {} is closed".format(port))
        s.close()
        # break

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ('you stopp it manually')

except socket.gaierror:
    print ("Cant resolve host name")
```

Comment: Try starting at port 53 to find out of it is specific to port 52.

Comment: Call `setdefaulttimeout` before creating the first socket object, it only affects sockets created after it is called

Answer (score 3):

```
for port in range(52,85):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
    ...
```

You first create the socket, then call `socket.setdefaulttimeout`. But from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout):

> socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
>  Set the default timeout in seconds
> (float) **for new socket** objects. When the socket module is first
> imported, the default is None. See settimeout() for possible values
> and their respective meanings.

Thus, the first socket you create is not affected from the default timeout, since you set it after the socket creation. That's why it takes that long.

Apart from that it does not make much sense to call `socket.setdefaulttimeout` again and again with the same value. Since the new setting will affect all newly created sockets it is sufficient to call it once before any socket gets created, i.e.

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
for port in range(52,85):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ...
```